# mouseDragged event reporting incorrect deltaX/deltaY

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm trying to implement mouse dragging support for views which I have placed on a background view. But when I'm dragging the controls, the mouse pointer seems to be "faster" than the views I'm dragging. I'm using the deltaX values in each `mouseDragged:` event to move the views. When compare the sum of all `NSEvent.deltaX` values to the difference between the initial and current `.locationInWindow.x`, a difference builds up (the `deltaX` sum is always less than the actual X difference). It looks like I'm "losing" `mouseDragged:` events somehow.

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    // - irrelevant code removed

    clickPos = theEvent.locationInWindow;
    sumDeltaX = 0.0;
}

- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseDragged:theEvent];

    // -irrelevant code removed

    sumDeltaX += theEvent.deltaX;
    NSLog(@"Drag: diff. start/current=%.0f ; sum of deltaX=%.0f", theEvent.locationInWindow.x-clickPos.x, sumDeltaX);
}
```

The result:

```
2015-05-19 13:52:48.927 MSB Playout 2[1124:497022] Drag: diff. start/current=2 ; sum of deltaX=2
2015-05-19 13:52:48.944 MSB Playout 2[1124:497022] Drag: diff. start/current=3 ; sum of deltaX=3
2015-05-19 13:52:48.961 MSB Playout 2[1124:497022] Drag: diff. start/current=6 ; sum of deltaX=5
2015-05-19 13:52:48.978 MSB Playout 2[1124:497022] Drag: diff. start/current=9 ; sum of deltaX=7
2015-05-19 13:52:48.995 MSB Playout 2[1124:497022] Drag: diff. start/current=12 ; sum of deltaX=10
2015-05-19 13:52:49.012 MSB Playout 2[1124:497022] Drag: diff. start/current=17 ; sum of deltaX=14
```

The effect is more visible when I drag slowly (=more events generated?); when I do a quick drag, I hardly lose anything.

- Is that a known problem, i.e. is deltaX/deltaY not guaranteed to be reliable?
- What is the suggested workaround? Using the difference between `mouseDown` and `mouseDragged` location would be possible, but doesn't look very elegant to me.

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Why? This is all the relevant code that is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: is sumDelta an int? do you modify sumDelta anywhere else?

Comment: Since `NSEvent.deltaX` is a CGFloat, `sumDeltaX`is a CGFloat, too. (That it's not an int is obvious from the format string, I think.) And no, of course I do not modify any value anywhere else, otherwise I wouldn't have claimed that this is all the relevant code. The `// - irrelevant code removed` comment just replace a few NSLog statements.

Answer (score 0):

I just came into the same problem. While i was dragging a NSBezierPath, i noticed exactly the same behaviour as you did.

I checked the deltaX and deltaY and noticed that they always change by integer values, like 1.0, 2.0 and so. Even if they are actually CGFloat numbers.

What i did is that i set a lastPoint variable in mouseDown event.
Then when dragging begins, i compute the difference between the currentPoint and lastPoint, thus building my deltaX and deltaY values, which i use to transform my NSBezierPath.